# asp mvc 2 EditorFor strange behavior

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, editorfor

ok i've defined a shared editor for string like the following

> <%@ Control Language="C#"
>   Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl"
>   %>   
>       <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model) %>      
>       <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model) %>
>       <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>
>   model) %>

now i'm calling the custom editor like this in another control

```
        <%= Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Username)%>
        <%= Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Email)%>
        <%= Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Password)%>
```

my model is like this

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Le nom d'utilisateur est requis.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [DisplayName("Nom d'utilisateur")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "L'email est requis.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [DisplayName("Courriel")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le mot de passe est requis.")]
    [ValidatePasswordLength]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Mot de passe")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

The only display that is rendered is the Email field.
The two others are not rendered ?
If i remove the DataType.Text and DataType.Password then all the display fields are rendered ??

Very strange behavior...

Someone knows why ?

Comment: can you tell my why you need the datatypes?

Comment: i could go without but why not?

Answer (score 0):

You need a ValidationSummary to show the errors from all properties in a model.  Otherwise, you will need a ValidationMessageFor for each property in the model.

This will work:

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>
```

Or this:

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model.UserName) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model.Email) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model.Password) %>
```

Comment: He didn't ask about validation messages.  how do you know he doesn't have a Validation summary in his parent view?

Comment: Since this question was just changed 3 hours ago and I answered it 7 months ago, I can't comment on the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the date.  however, the recent edit was just a re-tag, not content change to the question.

Answer (score 0):

DataType controls what type of template is used to render.  When you specify Text or Password, then MVC will select the default templates for those (they're built-in) and ignore your template.

Email works because there is no built-in email template, and thus it falls back to string.

EDIT: I think i misunderstood.  Are you saying they don't render at all?  Do you have blank Password and Text templates in your EditorTemplates folder?